# How Can i Get 5 Recent Post Title With Corresponding Link?

Tags: posts, get-posts, title

I Want to Add My Latest 5 Post Title with Corresponding Link in My Header Position.What was the Actual Php code?Am Newbie ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like an additional Loop on that page, right?
You might want to use:

```
<ul>
    <?php $posts_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5');
        while ($posts_query->have_posts()) : $posts_query->the_post();
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

Also read more here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_in_Action

Comment: it working fine.thx Daniel

Comment: Note that this method incurs unnecessary overhead, because, IIRC, `posts_per_page` doesn't limit the number of posts returned, but rather only limits the number of posts shown per page. So, even though you're only showing 5 posts, the query returns *all posts*. Thus, `get_posts()` is considerably lighter for returning recent posts.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php $recent_posts = get_posts('numberposts=5');
if($recent_posts) { ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) { ?>
        <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($recent->ID); ?>"><?php echo $recent->post_title; ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts
you need to change the html tags if you need a different output.

Comment: thx michael....

Comment: I prefer the `get_posts()` method, personally.